# How to hide the div which has placed inside inner div using jquery

Tags: jquery

I have the following div structure,

```
<div id="fancybox-content">
<iframe....>
<html>
<body>
<div class="main">
<div id="adminheader">...</div>
<div id="admininner">
<div class="admin-inner-bg">
<div class="left">-------</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
</iframe>
</div>
```

how to hide the div which has the class `left`.

Kindly help.

Comment: Your indentation really bothers! Can you fix it, please?

Comment: No, `left` is in an iframe. Are you sure jQuery browsers iframes too?

Comment: Is the content od the iframe coming fromt the same domain? In which context do you want to execute the code? In the iframe or in the parent page?

Comment: @Felix Kling i need to hide iframe content

Comment: @Dinesh: I got that, that is not what I was asking...

Comment: @Saeed: as long as the `<iframe>` doesn't target a foreign domain, yes it'll work just like that,.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if the content of iframe is from the same domain you can do

add id to your iframe

```
<iframe id="youriframeID"...>
.
.
```

and access the `div` with `class` left as

```
$('#youriframeID').contents().find('div.left').hide();
```

else if the contents of the iframe are from a different domain you have to create a server side proxy

**Edit(s)**

you can try the following

```
$('#youriframeID').contents().find('div.left')[0].hide();
```

if that didn't work wrap the code in

```
$("#youriframeID").ready(function () {
 $('#youriframeID').contents().find('div.left').hide();

}
```

this way the code will execute when the iframe is finished loading

Comment: Thanks iframe is coming from same domain, i tried it,But its not hiding

Answer (score 2):

jQuery has a hide function: http://api.jquery.com/hide/

```
$('.left').hide();
```

Comment: That'll hide EVERY div with the class 'left'. I think OP wants to be a little more specific?

Comment: @scobal Here hide left only when we have <div id="fancybox-content">

Comment: Oh right, the question reads "how to hide the div which has the class left." which I took to mean all <div class="left">

Answer (score 0):

`$("#fancybox-content .left").get().hide();`

Answer (score 0):

Thanks all your support,

I got it by working,

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#fancybox-frame').ready(function(){
       $('.left').hide();
    });
</script>
```